# jQuery upload script

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am looking for some script, that will allow me to preview image before uploading it AND delete selected images, before uploading it. It will be placed in a Wordpress front end page. I want images to be posted together with the rest of form fields.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gallery").on('change', function() {
      //Get count of selected files
      var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
      var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
      var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
      var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
      image_holder.empty();
      if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
        if (typeof(FileReader) != "undefined") {
          //loop for each file selected for uploaded.
          for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
              $("<img />", {
                "src": e.target.result,
                "class": "thumb-image"
              }).appendTo(image_holder);
            }
            image_holder.show();
            reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
          }
        } else {
          alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Pls select only images");
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
img.thumb-image {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
      <input name="gallery[]" id="gallery" multiple type="file">
    </span>
  </span>
  <div id="image-holder"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aside from the uploading, your code would seem to do what you need. Do you have a specific problem with it? If you're asking how do you upload the image then there's already several questions covering that if you search.

Comment: Add what have you have tried so far regarding "image removal" part.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't need this script to upload the files. Just need a solution to delete files before posting the form. I've searched a lot, but unfortunately couldn't find anything. I should've mention it, but I need single file removal for MULTIPLE file input. Deleting all the uploads is easy, but for single images I seems to be harder.

Comment: @besciualex What I tried is to let user remove all the files, but not a single ones. I've search for solution a lot, looking for solution, but unfortunately I've found nothing.

Comment: @RafałRawski please add that code here, so we can actual help you. The reason your question was downvoted is because you asked for stackoverflow community to write that code for you. We need to see what you have tried so far, and be sure you at least tried something.

Comment: @besciualex Achieving what I wanted is not possible with jQuery, I just needed the answer to my question not writing the code for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I have found out that this is not possible, so for others who look for answer just like me - look no further - you wont achieve it with jQuery. file input element is read only and it is not possible to edit it with script. Maybe for the better.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot delete a file using jquery. But you can display image before uploading using file api (not supported in all browser)

Comment: Read carefully. He meant to delete from input field, not from server. You select the images, preview them, remove from input everything you consider extra and hit the Submit button.